# Blow out the candle

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

Yesterday was his birthday.

> "Blow the candles."
>
> "Blow out the candles."

How do I say to blow the candle until the fire has been off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always:

"**Blow out** *the candles*."

or

"**Blow** *the candles* **out**."

"To blow out" is a phrasal verb that means, in this instance, "to extinguish".  It could also mean "to destroy (a team) in sports or a game":

"We **blew** *the other team* **out**.  It was a *blowout*."

or

"We **blew out** *the other team*.  It was a *blowout*."

It has other meanings as well, but when it deals with "fire", it's always "to blow out".

"The wind **blew** *the fire* **out**."

or

"The wind **blew out** *the fire*."